# How to show the following subset of continuous functions is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

I only have some general idea on how to prove this statement.

Let $F_n$ be the subset of $C[0,1]$ consisting of functions for which there is a point $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq n|x-x_0|\quad\text{for all }x\in[0,1]$$

How can we show that $F_n$ is closed?

My approach:

Let $f_n\in F_n$. To show $F_n$ is closed we need to show that the limit $f_n$ as $n\to\infty$ is in $F_n$. Then we need to show the limit also satisfies the condition above. Is my approach correct? How can I rigorously show that the limit exists and is in $F_n$?

If this approach is not a good approach, is there a better one?

I have little clue on how to proceed. Could somebody please lend me a hand? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $F_n$ is a closed subset of $C[0,1]$, you must show that if $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence in $F_n$ converging to some $f\in C[0,1]$, then in fact $f\in F_n$.

The hard part of the proof is finding the point $x_0$ for $f$. To do so, let $x_k$ be a point in $[0,1]$ for which
$$ |f_k(x)-f_k(x_k)|\leq n|x-x_k|$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then $\{x_k\}$ is a bounded sequence, hence there is a subsequence $x_{k_j}$ such that $\lim_{j\to\infty}x_{k_j}=x_0\in [0,1]$.

Now given $\varepsilon>0$, pick $j$ large enough that $||f_{k_j}-f||_{\infty}<\varepsilon$ and $|x_{k_j}-x_0|<\varepsilon$. Then
$$ |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq |f(x)-f_{k_j}(x)|+|f_{k_j}(x)-f_{k_j}(x_{k_j})|+|f_{k_j}(x_{k_j})-f_{k_j}(x_0)|+|f_{k_j}(x_0)-f(x_0)|$$
$$ < 2\varepsilon+n|x-x_{k_j}|+n|x_{k_j}-x_0|\leq n|x-x_0|+2\varepsilon+2n|x_{k_j}-x_0| $$
$$ <n|x-x_0|+(2n+2)\varepsilon$$
and since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, this shows that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq n|x-x_0|$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Thus $f\in F_n$.